# Efficient way to check for existence of object and set equal to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, I want to set a variable equal to an ActiveRecord object but only if it exists. For instance, I want to set the instance variable `@admin` equal to the admin with a given password I have passed in through params. This is how I am doing it now:

```
if Admin.find_by_email(params[:email])
   @admin = Admin.find_by_email(params[:email])
end
```

I need to check the existence of an admin with an email `'params[:email]'` to handle my edge case where an invalid email is passed in. However, this approach requires me doing 2 database requests. I would prefer to do only one and accomplish the same thing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the if statement.  Dynamic finders like find_by_email will return nil if they don't find anything.

Then when code depends on an admin exists

```
unless @admin.blank?
  #do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
@admin = Admin.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

And @admin will be equal to nil if no Admin is found

OR use a temp variable:

```
admin_tmp = Admin.find_by_email(params[:email])
@admin    = admin_tmp if admin_tmp.present?
```

Comment: Okay. I thought I had tried that and got an error. I probably just wasn't doing an `if @admin` check afterward. Thanks!